# Android Firebase weird limitToLast(1) behaviour

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using Firebase for Android and faced some misbehaviour of **limitToLast()** query. What I'm trying to do, is to get the last child of list, and iterate through other children of this node:

```
database.getReference().child("draws").limitToLast(1).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() { 
@Override                                                                                                       
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {                                                           
    for(DataSnapshot snap: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
        //Some work                                                                                             
        snap.getValue()                                                  
    }                                                                                                           
}                                                                                                               

@Override                                                                                                       
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {  
        //Some error handling                                                                                                                                                     
}                                                                                                               
});
```

Let's assume, I'm using limitToLast(1) in order to get the child **draws/2**(refer to the database snap below), which is the last in a draws list. And after, I'm using dataSnapshot.getChildren() to get the list of children of **draws/2** node. What I should get after iterating through the dataSnapshot.getChildren() list: "85", "86", "60", "7" as separate values with snap.getValue().toString() in the loop.

[image]

What I actually get, is the value of last child without accessing to its children. Result: "[85, 86, 60, 7]". It looks like dataSnapshot.getChildren() doesn't get children of node **draws/2**, but just gets a whole value of the node.

As a test, I tried to get rid of limitToLast(1) query and substitute with child("2") and everything worked fine.

It is possible that I misunderstood the functionality of limitToLast(), however, if it is true, how can I access children of last node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you execute a query against the Firebase Database, there will potentially be multiple results. So the snapshot contains a list of those results. Even if there is only a single result, the snapshot will contain a list of one result.

So your code will need to *first* find the `draws/2` child (by looping) and *then* loop over the children:

```
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {                                                           
    for(DataSnapshot snap: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
        System.out.println(snap.getKey()); // prints 2
        for (DataSnapshot snap2: snap.getChildren()){
            //Some work                                                                                             
            snap.getValue()                                                  
        }
    }                                                                                                           
}
```

It's typically easier to handle query results by using `addChildEventListener`, because then you'll get a separate call to `onChildAdded` for each child (and can thus skip the extra loop).

Btw: there are a lot of reasons why the [documentation for the Firebase Database doesn't use arrays](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data) and even [recommends against using arrays](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html). Ignore them at your own peril.

Comment: Thank you, Frank! Indeed, that is what I was looking for. I'm very glad you are actively moderating Firebase topic on StackOverflow. Your answers are very helpful