# Android Firebase Get Single node Values by child search

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hello This is my firebase  I'm trying to make query

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ldexn.png

I'm trying to get the Values of child "02" by searching where "name" = "Cafe"

```
        category.orderByChild("name").equalTo("Cafe").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Category catx = dataSnapshot.getValue(Category.class);

            Toast.makeText(AdminCategories.this, "xx"+catx.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            admCatId.setText(dataSnapshot.getKey());
            admCatName.setText(catx.getName());
            admCatImage.setText(catx.getImage());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

But I'm getting null using this code ..

I'm getting the desired result when I use

```
category.child("02").addValueEventListener(new .....)
```

Please note that I don't use any adapter or lists I just need to get the results of a single child by name searching..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you execute a query against the Firebase Database, there will potentially be multiple results. So the snapshot contains a list of those results. Even if there is only a single result, the snapshot will contain a list of one result.

Your `onDataChange` needs to handle that list, which it currently doesn't. The simplest change is to iterate over `dataSnapshot.getChildren()`:

```
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
  for (DataSnapshot categorySnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
    Category catx = categorySnapshot.getValue(Category.class);

    Toast.makeText(AdminCategories.this, "xx"+catx.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    admCatId.setText(categorySnapshot.getKey());
    admCatName.setText(catx.getName());
    admCatImage.setText(catx.getImage());
  }
}
```

Also see:

- [Firebase return child that have biggest value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44156023/firebase-return-child-that-have-biggest-value)
- [JavaScript Firebase: Query Snapshot Always Null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46043462/javascript-firebase-query-snapshot-always-null)
- [Android Firebase weird limitToLast(1) behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41955706/android-firebase-weird-limittolast1-behaviour)

Comment: Thank you very much for the information, this helped me alot :)